# Confusion in usage of verb in interrogative past tense

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I know that whenever we use "did" in any sentence, the following verb has to be in present form. But I have a confusion:-
In plain English it should be:- **Did you forget switching it off?** 
But if we jumble up the words, should we write it like this:- ***Forgot* switching it off, did you?** or like this:- ***Forget* switching it off, did you?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb following *DO* is not in *present* form but in the *infinitive* form. (To be sure, this is a rather artificial distinction, since in most cases the two forms are identical; but they are different for one very common verb, *BE*.)

Accordingly, there's no present form here to confuse you. *Forgot* is the form you want.

However, in this context *forget* takes a *bare infinitive* rather than a *gerund*, so the expressions you're looking for are:

> Did you forget to switch it off?
>   You forgot to switch it off, didn't you.
>   Forgot to switch it off, did you?